# Terminating unused SDI/BNC input

Tags: video, bnc

I use the Magewell Eco Capture Quad SDI M.2 (a small form factor quad-channel) capture device which keeps overheating after a few minutes (up to 100 C). I've read that this might be due to cameras not being connected and SDI inputs unused. Since I have only a single SDI camera, I was thinking if I can try terminating inputs with BNC 50 or 75 Ohm caps.

Is this a common practice for SDI devices?

Comment: Is it running at 3.3V?.. What state are each LED at?

Comment: If it's specifically SDI, you'll want 75 ohms.

Comment: I have 50 Ohms with me :) Would that be a big issue if I used them before I get 75 Ohms?

Comment: You could use 0 Ohms even.

Answer (score 1):

The SDI input will already have a 75 ohm to ground and no connection or signal should not affect device power consumption.

Given the board has a significant heatsink yet only rated to draw about 8 W, something appears to have gone wrong during installation.
[image]
ESD handling precautions must be adhered to.  Consult with distributor for an RMA.

**Power consumption should not increase with no input signal connection.**

The SDI input should match TI's standard circuit [design.](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lmh0344)

[image]

[image]

There is a latchup effect of shorting out the CMOS chip if a transient occurs outside the supply range. It should be only a temporary fault if no burning smell or smoke occurs. ;)  *[*See above caution during installation.](https://www.magewell.com/kb/000050004/detail)**

Comment: "Given the board has a significant heatsink yet only rated to draw about 8 W, something appears to have gone wrong during installation."

Can you expand? I'm consulting with Magewell, they get 80C with a single input on an actively cooled card. 

I'm also thinking about M.2 adapter I'm using - the only PCIe to M.2 M-key adapters I found are for NVMe SSDs  and it looks like their design might vary

Comment: Is adequate active cooling being used in your case?

Comment: At this stage, I'm trying to figure out with the vendor what is the definition of an adequate working temperature. There was no guidance on using active cooling till their last support ticket response so I need to revisit it.

Comment: The core temp should be < 85'C and I recall reading it was stated to as 79'C core temp  without any conditions as if it didn't matter for input signals.. But there must be either convection air flow or active air flow which can make a huge difference in heatsink temp rise especially if 1m/s air velocity thru the sink.  It is poorly defined and reliability depends on minimizing temp rise.  For CPU core, I would expect < 75'C core temp in order to minimize rise in slew rate of signals which I would expect to be more critical.

Comment: Thanks, I'll work on the active cooling then

Comment: I meant minimize rise of slew time of CPU clock edges or "reduction of slew rate".. CMOS runs slower with rising temp due to increased RdsOn into a fixed capacitance.